# Model binding not working for nested object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, postman

I am trying to bind data in my model posted from postman in my below model:

```
public class VariantModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public List<SubvariantModel> Subvariants { get; set; }
}

public class SubvariantModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Document { get; set; }
}
```

Every property is getting populated but only `Document` property is coming null as you can see here :

[image]

But surprisingly when i inspect http request object i see that file :

[image]

This is how i am posting data from POSTMAN : 
[image]

[image]

**Code :**

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromForm]VariantModel emp)
{
    var d = HttpContext.Request;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what could be the issue here?

**Update :**

[image]

Comment: Your key naming is very odd. The names should really be `Subvariants[0].Document`, not `Subvariants[0][Document]`. It's surprising that this actually works for `Id` and `Description`, but perhaps it simply doesn't for some reason with `IFormFile`. Seems odd, but I honestly don't see anything else wrong.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I tried like this Subvariants[0].Document as well but still getting null and yes indeed I am also not getting whats the problem here.Is this a bug in asp.net webapi core with model binder?

Comment: Not at all. This is *very* basic code, and I've run code virtually just like this. As long as the name in the post body follows the proper conventions for binding (which these seem to), then it will bind.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Then why this is not working right now.May be you have not taken IFormFile in your nested model.Is there any solution for this?

Comment: No, I've definitely done that. It's probably better to say that this is such a fundamental things, that even if there *was* a bug, it would be found and stomped almost immediately. There's millions of developers using this stuff every day. Based on what you've been able to provide, I can't spot the problem, but I can pretty much guarantee it's not the framework.

Comment: @ChrisPratt If you want i can send you the solution but its all the default code generated by visual studio when i create webapi project

Comment: @ChrisPratt I have updated my question to include asp.net core version

Comment: I just tested your code with `ASP.NET Core 2.0` and everything worked fine for me. Could you please share your project on github and share the requests you performed via postman?

Comment: Could you try to  create a new simple Web API to test if the Document has the value  via the postman?

Comment: Having the same issue. 
FromForm binds everything correctly, except for nested object. It is constantly null. 
Adding 
```csharp
if(Request.Form["meta"][0] != null)
            {
                request.Meta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntityAttachmentMeta>(Request.Form["meta"][0]);
            }
```
Binds it normally. It's like the .net core binder doesn't handle it at all

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue I encountered as well. It is a known issue with nesting IFormFile as a View Model property in .NET Core v2.2.

The fix that worked for me is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347606/iformfile-as-a-nested-viewmodel-property).