# ASP.NET Core Upload Multiple File Web API model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

I want to upload multiple files and used `IFormFile` to upload file using asp.net core 5 but the problem is it shows me `string` data type instead of the `IFormFile`. Can I just override the field `attachment: "string"` property to `File` object?  See details below:

**Sample json data**

```json
id: 1122,
name: "yourname",
address: "your complete address",
attachments: [{
  "Id": 0,
  "Name": "string",
  "attachment": "string" // file attachment, I expect to be form upload button or similar
}] // please do note that this will have maximum of 5 arrays
// can attachment: string json property can be override with File object?
```

**Main Model**

```cs
public class MainModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

**Attachment Model**

```cs
public class Attachment
{
   [Required]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [Required]
   [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
   public IFormFile Attachment { get; set; } // this is weird, instead of upload file it shows string instead.
}
```

**Main Controller**

```cs
[HttpPut("main/update")]
public IActionResult UpdateMain([FromForm] MainModel model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      var result = _test.UpdateMain(model);
      return Ok(new { data = result });
   }
   return BadRequest();
}
```

I don't know why it has a `string` DataType into and it doesn't make sense for me.

[image]

The data being sent to the web api is a `File` object which it doesn't make sense.  Can someone help out in this one?

Comment: What are `Id` and `Name` in your `Attachments` I mean where they come from when you have not uploaded anything?

Comment: its a sample data inside the class model inside itself,

Comment: What is the issue? 
1] In Database, it shows string type instead of a blob. 
2] from react side, it passes the file but here in aspnet, it does not show?

Comment: @Nilay thats exactly my question and also how to pass data into it? can I just override it by passing a `File` object?

Comment: You are using IFormFile in Nested object which is a known bug and not going to fixed! So You need to flow this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56352648/2251733

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IList<IFormFile>` in your `attachment`. So your model would be like this:

```
public class MainModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public IList<IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

In this way `Attachments` property contains all the selected files in your client you have chosen.
Over each item of Attachments you have its FileName and some other useful data like `FileSize`, ...

Comment: yeah I think there are no option for now, I think I go with this route and create a separate list of attachment details and map it through `Zip` Linq function.  Anyway, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The following works for in net 6 for me, instead of model we can get files from HttpContext too:

```
    [HttpPost("Upload")]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            //processing / upload
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```